# Backup of folder + database - Python

Tags: python, bash, postgresql, backup, archiving

I feel like this is quite delicate,

I have various folders whith projects I would like to backup into a zip/tar file, but would like to avoid backing up files such as **pyc** files and temporary files.

I also have a Postgres db I need to backup.

---

Any tips for running this operation as a python script?

Also, would there be anyway to stop the process from hogging resources in the process?

---

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Linux (or any other form of Unix, such as MacOSX), a simple way to reduce a process's priority -- and therefore, indirectly, its consumption of CPU if other processes want some -- is the [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)) command.  In Python (same OSs), [os.nice](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=nice#os.nice) lets your program "make itself nicer" (reduce priority &c).

For backing up a PostgreSQL DB, I recommend [PostgreSQL's own tools](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/backup.html); for zipping up a folder except the pyc files (and temporary files -- however it is you identify those), Python is quite suitable.  For example:

```
>>> os.chdir('/tmp/az')
>>> f = open('/tmp/a.zip', 'wb')
>>> z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w')
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
...   for fn in files:
...     if fn.endswith('.pyc'): continue
...     fp = os.path.join(root, fn)
...     z.write(fp)
... 
>>> z.close()
>>> f.close()
>>>
```

this zips all files in said subtree except those ending in `.pyc` (without compression -- if you want compression, add a third argument `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` to the `zipfile.ZipFile` call).  Could hardly be easier.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you can use tar with `--exclude` option. an example, to exclude your `.pyc` files and temp files (in this example, `.tmp`)

```
$ tar zcvf backup.tar.gz --exclude "*.tmp" --exclude "*.pyc"
```

use the `z` option to zip it up as well.

Answer (score 1):

With today's multicore cpus, you may find that cpu is not the bottle neck. It is now far more likely to the the disk I/O that needs to be shared better.

Linux has the ionice command to allow you to control this

> ionice(1)
>
> NAME
>
> ```
>    ionice - get/set program io scheduling class and priority
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    ionice [[-c class] [-n classdata ] [-t]] -p PID [PID ...]
>
>    ionice [-c class] [-n classdata ] [-t] COMMAND [ARG ...]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          This  program sets or gets the io scheduling class and priority for a
>   program.  If no arguments
>          or just -p is given, ionice will query the current io scheduling
>   class and  priority  for  that
>          process.

Answer (score 1):

Backup is at least as much about the importance of **recovery** using whatever backup you make.

The right way to back up source code is to **keep source files in a VCS (version control system)**, and back up the VCS repository. Exclude any auto-generated easily-replaced files (like those `*.pyc` files, etc.) from the VCS repository. I recommend [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) for very efficient storage and user-friendliness, but your team will likely already have a VCS they prefer.

For backup of a PostgreSQL database, it's best to use `pg_dump` to **regularly dump the database to a text file**, compress that, and back up the result. This is because the backup then becomes restorable on any machine, by re-playing the database dump into another PostgreSQL server.

As for how to automate it: you would be best using a Bash program for the purpose, since it's just a matter of connecting some commands to files, which is what the shell excels at.